# JGoodies JTextfield forces cursor to beginning of jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextfield, jgoodies

I bind my JTextfield by simply doing

```
ValueModel valueModel = adapter.getBuferedModel(propertyName);
JTextField textField = BasicComponentFactory.createLongField(valueModel, numberFormat);
```

Whenever I mouse click in the JTextfield, it forces the cursor to the beginning of the JTextfield. I want to be able to edit the JTextfield where I click at so that if I want to append text to the field, I can click on the end once and have the cursor be there. Right now I have to click once, and then click again to get the cursor where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to have nothing to do with JGoodies, it has to do with formatted text fields.

This link saved me! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201873/jformattedtextfield-caret-position-on-focus)